# Next step when troubleshooting a PS/2 keyboard PCB with good cable

Tags: pcb, troubleshooting

I received a PS/2 keyboard (TypeMatrix 2020) which was known to be broken, with
some hope that I may be able to fix it. I don't have a lot of experience with
electronics, but I know the very basics. However, I'm unsure what to look for
next.

I have ensured the cable is working, so let's get that out of the way first.

The PCB inside the keyboard, which I copied to the best of my ability, appears
to be designed like

[image: PCB inside TypeMatrix 2020 keyboard]

where "IC" in reality refers to a DIP40 controller, but the pins not included
here are either intentionally unconnected or data lines going off to the key
matrix.

I read that old capacitors are a common problem, so – not knowing how to check
for that – I measured the resistance across all capacitors. Only C1, which is of
a different type from the others, gave me any reading at all (a high 10 MOhm ish
number, but steadily decreasing as I kept the probes on it). That feels like too
high a number to matter in practise, but is that so?

C1 is marked 10 uF, 25 V. The other three are apparently ceramic-type, but their markings decode to C2 being 100 nF, while C3 and C4 are 47 pF.

What would be the next step to check?

(Side question, not relevant to main issue: What is the purpose of the coils L1 and L2? I assume they form some kind of filter?)

Comment: (a) Can you add a clear, close-up photo of the PCB showing those components? (b) If it isn't clear on that photo, can you add the numbers from the top of the DIP40 IC? There were some standard kb controllers, so if it is a known part number, there might be a public datasheet for it. (c) "*I have ensured the cable is working*" How did you do that, exactly? (d) What test equipment do you have available, and know how to use? (e) Define "broken" e.g. no LEDs light on boot? No response to any keypress? (f) What is the history of this kb - what happened between the kb working and being "broken"?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a reverse engineering, modification, or repair question. Please be aware that such questions must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being discussed, so that you can ask specific, focused questions that can be answered concisely. More information can be found here: [Is asking how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2478/11683).

Comment: @SamGibson (a) When I get to the location of the keyboard, i will do so! (b) The is marked EM83P100P and manufactured by LAN. (c) Measured resistance from PS/2 connector pin to PCB connection. (d) Pretty much only a soldering iron and a digital multimeter capable of current, resistance and voltage. (f) Not known, got it for the price of shipping, seller couldnt tell me more than "either it or my USB adapters are broken".

Comment: @DaveTweed: I have tried spinning it in a way that's generally useful and suited to the Q&A format. Do you have concrete suggestions for improvement?

Comment: @kqr - Thanks. (a) I look forward to seeing that photo. (b) Unfortunately I can't find a datasheet for that kb controller IC, which will impact diagnosis - can you search too? (FYI manufacturer is Elan Microelectronics hence "EM" at start of part number). (c) FYI that continuity testing won't always detect *intermittent* cable break faults. (d) Lack of a 'scope will impact diagnosis opportunities. (e) Still required. (f) Lack of previous history will also impact diagnosis, since nothing can be eliminated nor specifically focussed upon. || I'm waiting for the photo before commenting on L1 & L2.

Comment: @SamGibson I have looked for a datasheet but also come up emtry handed. (e) Sorry? missed that. I plug the keyboard in then power on the computer. The keyboard blinks all three leds with maybe 200 ms on, 50 ms off, and keeps doing that until computer is powered off. It does not respond to keypresses. I understand all lights on means keyboard self-test, but then things get hazy.

Comment: Did you check that you are getting full 5 V on the keyboard? One possibility is that you are powering it via the CLK or DATA line and that's enough to charge the capacitors enough to turn it on, light the LEDs and have the voltage collapse, charge the caps again, ....